# Need Regex to match 8 numbers and words

Tags: python, regex

I hope I can explain this clearly enough. First, I am a regex noob, so please forgive my ignorance. Now, I am setting up a a system to detect an 8-digit number, starting with one or two zeros, AND/OR a pre-defined list of words. I need to detect the number whether or not the words are found along with it, or even connected to the number. But, I **don't** want it to detect the number if it contains all zeros, regardless of whether or not it is found with, or attached to a word in the list. I also do not want to detect any numbers starting or ending with any other characters, like a dash or slash. This may not be possible, but I thought I would ask anyway. I am currently using this formula, realizing it only finds numbers: \b(?!0+$)\d{8}\b

Here's a breakdown of what I am looking to do:

**DETECT:** 01234567 wordfromlist OR wordfromlist 012345678 OR wordfromlist01234567 OR 01234567wordfromlist

**DON'T DETECT:** 00000000 wordfromlist OR *wordfromlist* 0000000 OR 00000000wordfromlist OR wordfromlist00000000 OR

**DON'T DETECT:** 01234567- OR -01234567 OR /01234567/, etc

I hope I was able to explain this properly. If not, I'll try again. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Try this... `(?<=[a-zA-Z]|\s)\d+[1-9]+\d+(?=[a-zA-Z]|\s)` . https://regex101.com/r/QSEE9C/1

Comment: Also I did not put a constraint of 8 digits as one of your numbers is of length 9 `012345678`

Comment: `(?<=[a-zA-Z]|\s)\d*[1-9]+\d+(?=[a-zA-Z]|\s)` the earlier one wouldn't match `100000000`

Comment: "starting with one or two zeros, AND/OR a pre-defined list of words" So does that mean if the word from a pre-defined list is present, there is no longer a requirement to start with one or two zeros and just 8 digits is required ?. Also, can the latter 6 or 7 digits be a zero or must they be non-zero.

Comment: Thanks @bulbus! That mostly works. i just need to limit it to 8 numbers. i mistyped the number in my original post.

Comment: @R.Sharp, the requirement to start with one or two zeros is constant and does not change. all of these numbers will/must start with one or two zeros. Yes, the latter 6 or 7 digits can contain a zero. so, 01230456 needs to match.

Comment: @bfontaine, I've really only tried variations of the formula I posted, \b(?!0+$)\d{8}\b. Also tried (?<!\d)(\d{8})(?!\d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z]|\s|^)\d*[1-9]+\d*(?=[a-zA-Z]|\s|$)
```

Let me break it down to explain...
 1. `(?:^|(?<=[a-zA-Z\s]))` Positive lookbehind`(?<=`, match only no.s preceeded by space or alphabets. OR start of line.Put both in non capturing group `(?:`
 2. `\d*`                No.s should start with zero or more digits from `[0-9]`
 
 3. `[1-9]+`             No.s should've atleast one digit in `[1-9]`  
 4. `\d*`                Followed by zero or more digits in `[0-9]` 
 5. `(?:(?=[a-zA-Z\s])|$)` Positive lookahead`(?=`, match only no.s followed by space or alphabets. OR end of line.Put both in non capturing group `(?:`

Note that I did not constrain the number of digits as one of your sequences is of length 9 `012345678`

If you want the constraint of 8 digits then please use [this](https://regex101.com/r/QSEE9C/3)..

```
(?:^|(?<=[a-zA-Z\s]))0(?!0{7})\d{7}(?:(?=[a-zA-Z\s])|$)
```

1. `0` Start with Zero
2. `(?!0{7})` Negative lookahead `(?!` Don't follow the first zero with seven zeros
3. `\d{7}` Match with any digits of seven in length(of course after *2* is satisfied)

Edited to use python flavor for the regex, sorry my mistake that I overlooked & used pcre instead of python.
[Regex For Python here](https://regex101.com/r/QSEE9C/4)

Comment: What happened to our entire conversation here? All comments are now gone? what's up with that.

Comment: can you email me at troy.brokenshire@gmail.com, please?

Comment: thanks. I can't get anything to work, but I think I'll just have to go with what I have.

Comment: The tools I use only allow simple regex code. I can't add python code.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out. I cannot reply on the chat, as my reputation is too low.

Comment: ok, let me know how it goes... I added a bit of information as well, to help you understand your tool.

Comment: I'm getting the "(?<= A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width" error again on regex101

Comment: can you give me the link?

Comment: also, how do I make it case insensitive?

Comment: unfortunately you've to do via code `re.compile(r'my-regex-expression', re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: if it were javascript then regex can be sent as `/my-regex-expression/i` the last i after the slash is for `ignore case`

Comment: this might be easier if we communicate privately. I can reveal a bit about exactly what I am trying to accomplish. Can you email me at troy.brokenshire@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

tests = ["01234567", "00000000", "01234567-"]

final = [i for i in tests if re.findall("(^0{1,2})[1-9]{6,7}\d$", i)]
```

Output:

```
['01234567']
```

Comment: You can drop the parentheses around `[1-9]` since you’re not using the group, as well as around `\d$`.

Comment: @bfontaine thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: This will only match if the numbers are appearing at the beginning of a line `^` right? https://regex101.com/r/n4KCDa/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm less than convinced you can do all you want in a single regex.
It might be best to start with one which identifies the occurrences of 8 digits (with or without your words from the predefined list) and then hands that to the next stage of processing.

Something like this would return a list of 'match' objects which could then be interrogated further :

```
import re

strings_to_test = ['01234567' , '00000000', 'special-word 01234567'
                   'special-word01234567', 'special-word01234567-']
digits_present = [re.search("(\S*) *([0-9]{8}) *(\S*)", i)
                                           for i in strings_to_test]
for match in digits_present:
    print "{0:s} = {1:s} : {2:s} : {3:s}".format(match.group(0),
                     match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3))
```

returns :

```
01234567 =  : 01234567 : 
00000000 =  : 00000000 : 
special-word 01234567 = special-word : 01234567 : 
special-word01234567 = special-word : 01234567 : 
special-word01234567- = special-word : 01234567 : -
```

As you can see match.group(2) is your set of digits, which you can now test is not all zeros.
match.group(1) and match.group(3) are the text either side of your digits which you can check for the presence of one of the words in your list, for inclusion, or the other characters, for exclusion.
Finally you'd need to check that if neither of the the outer matches were words from your list that the digits began with one or two zeros.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I am constrained to just using regex entries